# [Python]Get a XPath Value from Steam and print it

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, python-requests

I want to get an XPATH-Value from a Steamstoresite, e.g. http://store.steampowered.com/app/234160/. On the right side are 2 boxes. The first one contains Title, Genre, Developer ... I just need the Genre here. There is a different count on every game. Some have 4 Genres, some just one. And then there is another block, where the gamefeatures are listet (like Singleplayer, Multiplayer, Coop, Gamepad, ...)

I need all those values.
Also sometimes there is an image between (PEGI/USK)
http://store.steampowered.com/app/233290.

```
import requests
from lxml import html

page = requests.get('http://store.steampowered.com/app/234160/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

blockone = tree.xpath(".//*[@id='main_content']/div[4]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]")
blocktwo = tree.xpath(".//*[@id='main_content']/div[4]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]")

print "Detailblock:" , blockone
print "Featureblock:" , blocktwo
```

This is the code I have so far. When I try it it just prints:

```
Detailblock: [<Element div at 0x2ce5868>]
Featureblock: [<Element div at 0x2ce58b8>]
```

How do I make this work?

Comment: As a side note, all of these divs have distinct classes, and the layout just changed a couple months ago… are you sure you want to get them by index?

Comment: Also, doesn't steam have an API for this that you can use instead of screen-scraping?

Comment: You are right... But it isn't in the official API documents...
I found it on the TF2 Wiki at http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/User:RJackson/StorefrontAPI ...

So the url I need is e.g.
store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails/?appids=234160&filters=genres,categories&l=english

Now I need to find out how to work with JSON... But I think I can manage that...

Comment: Cool, sounds like that should be a lot easier, and more robust.

Answer (score 0):

`xpath` returns a list of matching elements. You're just printing out that list.

If you want the first element, you need `blockone[0]`. If you want all elements, you have to loop over them (e.g., with a comprehension).

And meanwhile, what do you want to print for each element? The direct inner text? The HTML for the whole subtree rooted at that element? Something else? Whatever you want, you need to use the appropriate method on the [`Element`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html) type to get it; lxml can't read your mind and figure out what you want, and neither can we.

It sounds like what you really want is just some elements deeper in the tree. You could `xpath` your way there. (Instead of going through all of the elements one by one and relying on index as you did, I'm just going to write the simplest way to get to what I think you're asking for.)

```
genres = [a.text for a in blockone[0].xpath('.//a')]
```

Or, really, why even get that `blockone` in the first place? Why not just `xpath` directly to the elements you wanted in the first place?

```
gtags = tree.xpath(".//*[@id='main_content']/div[4]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]//a")
genres = [a.text for a in gtags]
```

Also, you could make this a lot simpler—and a lot more robust—if you used the information in the tags instead of finding them by explicitly walking the structure:

```
gtags = tree.xpath(".//div[@class='glance_tags popular_tags']//a")
```

Or, since there don't seem to be any other `app_tag` items anywhere, just:

```
gtags = tree.xpath(".//a[@class='app_tag']")
```

Comment: I tryed to use blockone[0].text but it does just print a few linebreaks. I want for the first block, the tags which stand after genre in pure text format and for the second block the features in pure textformat and without the icons. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Well, if you want those sub-elements, why not just use `xpath` again? For example, you want the text of each `a` element under the `div` with class `glance_tags` that's a descendant of `blockone[0]`. Why get the whole text of `blockone[0]` and try to parse it, instead of iterating over the `a` elements and getting their text?